# How to make sure .sln file open project correctly across team members?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, version-control

I check in my `.sln`(no proj file) file to TFS.

When other team member download the project from TFS and open the `.sln` file, visual studio 2010 said it cannot load the project correctly.

The exact message from team member visual studio is:

`One or more projects in the solution were not loaded correctly. Please see the Output Window for details.`

The Output Windows message is:

`D:\111\222 : error  : Unable to open the Web site 'D:\111\222'.  The Web site 'D:\111\222' does not exist.`

The project is actually not loaded in the solution explorer and I am certain that all the `.cs`, `.aspx` and etc. are in my team member TFS local folder.

I believe it's due to `.sln` file point my TFS local folder.

My TFS local folder is `d:\111\222`

Other team member TFS local folder is `d:\333\444`

How should I check in my `.sln` correctly, so that the project will open correctly by my team member no matter where their TFS local folder located?

Comment: "cannot load"? Please add more information about this...

Comment: Sounds as if the checked-in files contains hardcoded paths. Try open your .sln .suo, .*csproj with another text editor, fix and check-in again

Comment: @GiulioVian Fix it to relative path? How? I'm gonna google it but if you can point me to the right direction, that will be great.

Comment: @Pop My suggestion is to open you .sln with notepad and check if there are absolute paths and change them to relative. It may be that you have to repeat this with other files (.csproj, .suo, .user).

Answer (score 0):

Check if your team member can open successfully after manully copying Web site to `'D:\111\222'` on their machine.

Suggest you setting up an IIS virtual directory to point to the location the site is running from.

Comment: I use visual studio 2010 to `File` -> `Open` -> `Web Site...`, it will create a solution file for me with relative path. That solve it for me.